# NSInvalidArgumentException during instantiation of realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Getting error while instantiating object of realm. Check the mentioned below code.

import RealmSwift

```
class DB {
    let db: Realm!
    init() {
        self.db = try! Realm()
    } 
}
```

In the viewController, I am trying to instantiate a database object.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var database: DB!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.database = DB.init()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    } 
}
```

Error message in console is:

```
2016-10-24 07:56:10.852860 ExpenseIt[1009:8624] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEventFiltered, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-10-24 07:56:10.860310 ExpenseIt[1009:8624] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEventIncoming, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-10-24 07:56:10.869424 ExpenseIt[1009:8619] subsystem: com.apple.BaseBoard, category: MachPort, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
2016-10-24 07:56:10.881984 ExpenseIt[1009:8580] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: StatusBar, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-10-24 07:56:10.932322 ExpenseIt[1009:8619] subsystem: com.apple.libsqlite3, category: logging, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-10-24 07:56:10.965507 ExpenseIt[1009:8619] subsystem: com.apple.network, category: , enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-10-24 07:56:10.965843 ExpenseIt[1009:8619] [] tcp_connection_create_with_endpoint_and_parameters 2 static.realm.io 443
2016-10-24 07:56:10.966149 ExpenseIt[1009:8633] [] tcp_connection_create_with_endpoint_and_parameters 1 api.mixpanel.com 443
2016-10-24 07:56:10.966 ExpenseIt[1009:8580] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSInvocation getArgument:atIndex:]: struct with unknown contents found while getting argument at index -1'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108c9334b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010621421e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108c18fe9 -[NSInvocation getArgument:atIndex:] + 473
    3   Foundation                          0x0000000105da76d6 _NSGetValueWithMethod + 174
    4   Foundation                          0x0000000105d1bf2b -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] + 283
    5   Realm                               0x0000000105748b13 -[RLMObjectBase valueForKey:] + 86
    6   Realm                               0x0000000105757fce -[RLMProperty initSwiftPropertyWithName:indexed:linkPropertyDescriptor:property:instance:] + 354
    7   Realm                               0x000000010574ba6a +[RLMObjectSchema propertiesForClass:isSwift:] + 730
    8   Realm                               0x000000010574a966 +[RLMObjectSchema schemaForObjectClass:] + 437
    9   Realm                               0x00000001057c367e _ZL16RLMRegisterClassP10objc_class + 145
    10  Realm                               0x00000001057c3eba __25+[RLMSchema sharedSchema]_block_invoke + 12
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108c1a9d6 __65-[__NSDictionaryM enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 102
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108c1a8af -[__NSDictionaryM enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 159
    13  Realm                               0x00000001057c3d3b +[RLMSchema sharedSchema] + 142
    14  Realm                               0x00000001057bafec +[RLMRealm realmWithConfiguration:error:] + 1230
    15  RealmSwift                          0x0000000105634a24 _TFC10RealmSwift5RealmcfzT_S0_ + 100
    16  ExpenseIt                           0x000000010555d845 _TFC9ExpenseIt2DBcfT_S0_ + 37
    17  ExpenseIt                           0x000000010555d8bf _TFC9ExpenseIt2DBCfT_S0_ + 47
    18  ExpenseIt                           0x000000010555c8e8 _TFC9ExpenseIt14ViewController11viewDidLoadfT_T_ + 88
    19  ExpenseIt                           0x000000010555c972 _TToFC9ExpenseIt14ViewController11viewDidLoadfT_T_ + 34
    20  UIKit                               0x00000001074f506d -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1258
    21  UIKit                               0x00000001074f54a0 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    22  UIKit                               0x00000001073bf045 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 71
    23  UIKit                               0x00000001073bf796 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 293
    24  UIKit                               0x00000001073d30a9 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
    25  UIKit                               0x000000010734c259 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4818
    26  UIKit                               0x00000001073523b9 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1731
    27  UIKit                               0x000000010734f539 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
    28  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010bb5c76b __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
    29  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010bb5c5e4 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 189
    30  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010bb5c96d -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108c38311 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108c1d59c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108c1ca86 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108c1c494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    35  UIKit                               0x000000010734ddb6 -[UIApplication _run] + 434
    36  UIKit                               0x0000000107353f34 UIApplicationMain + 159
    37  ExpenseIt                           0x000000010555e5ff main + 111
    38  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010716168d start + 1
    39  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
2016-10-24 07:56:10.966479 ExpenseIt[1009:8619] [] tcp_connection_start 2 starting
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Would greatly appreciate if someone could help me on this.

Comment: Show the whole message of the `NSException`. There should be more about it.

Comment: Thanks Larme for replying. I have added the full console output. Let me know if something else is required.

Comment: Could you please share your full schema (Realm model classes), since it appears there's something there that Realm isn't parsing correctly.

Comment: Hi jpsim, can you please tell me where to get the full schema?? As i have installed the framework using dynamic installation as per  https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/

Comment: Hi jpsim, i think now i understood what u meant. Sorry for wasting valuable time of you guys. This was happening because i had a field in my model whose datatype was decimal and Realm doesn't support decimal.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys for wasting your valuable time. **xcode threw error during runtime because of using unsupported datatype in model.**

It seems with what jpsim told, i re-looked and found that i was using a datatype which is not supported by Realm. And even though i was not instantiating object of my model, Realm still somehow detects it and flag it as error. Although i hoped if the error was more clear.

Thanks to all of you guys for helping me find answer.